# Json string to Array of Tuples

Tags: c#, json, linq

I need to convert Json string
e.g. `["value1","value2","value3","value4"]`
into a array of Tuples such as,

```
Tuple<value1,value2>
Tuple<value3,value4>
```

I was thinking of converting the json string into string [] and then convert it to one Tuple at a time, but wondering if there is an easy way of doing it?

Comment: Thats a simple array. Use Take(2) method from Linq to create tuples

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Linq`  as shown below:

```
var jArrayString = "[\"value1\",\"value2\",\"value3\",\"value4\"]";
var jArray = JArray.Parse(jArrayString);
var tuples = jArray.Select((j, index) => index % 2 == 0 
                       ? new Tuple<string, string>(jArray[index].Value<string>(), jArray[index + 1].Value<string>()) 
                       : null)
                    .Where(t => t != null);
```

You can check the fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/g1MFjb

Note - the above may not be a optimized way. the same can be done using a simple for loop :).